# File picker in Ionic1

Tags: ionic-framework, filepicker.io

I am creating an Ionic1 hybrid app and I need to implement filePicker functionality. I have tried using recommended plugin discussed here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/recommended-android-ios-file-chooser-plugin/20761/8 But it gives error that FilePicker not defined.Any help on this? or any other plugin that can help me pick files for both android and IOS.

Comment: Can you add error logs

Comment: @Dolo no specified error log. It just goes in error response block

Answer (score 0):

For ionic1, I recommend to use the native HTML5 file picker, for example for uploading an image use the following:

```
<input id="file-image" type="file" accept="image/*" ng-model='input.image' base-sixty-four-input />
```

You can change the **accept** attribute to match the MIME type you want.

This solution works perfectly and tested on Android and iOS.